I need to send an email with a batch Class that summarises all opportunity amounts
I just don't know why this code does not work, if anyone has any suggestions, i'm happy to hear them!
public with sharing class OppAmountForAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    System.debug('Start method initiated');
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT AccountId, Name, Email 
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Is_Primary_Contact__c = TRUE AND AccountId <> NULL
    ]);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> contacts){
    System.debug('Execute method initiated with ' + contacts.size() + ' contacts');
    List<Id> accountIdList = new List<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountToContactsMap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();

    // Collect Account IDs and map contacts to their accounts
    for(Contact con : contacts){
        System.debug('Processing contact: ' + con.Name + ' with AccountId: ' + con.AccountId);
        accountIdList.add(con.AccountId);
        if (!accountToContactsMap.containsKey(con.AccountId)) {
            accountToContactsMap.put(con.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
        }
        accountToContactsMap.get(con.AccountId).add(con);
    }

    if(!accountIdList.isEmpty()){
        System.debug('Account IDs to process: ' + accountIdList);

        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIdList]);
        Map<Id, Decimal> openOppAmounts = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        Map<Id, Decimal> wonOppAmounts = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        Map<Id, Decimal> lostOppAmounts = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

        // Aggregate opportunity amounts
        for(AggregateResult ar : [
            SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) sumAmount
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdList AND StageName = 'Open'
            GROUP BY AccountId
        ]){
            openOppAmounts.put((Id)ar.get('AccountId'), (Decimal)ar.get('sumAmount'));
        }

        for(AggregateResult ar : [
            SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) sumAmount
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdList AND StageName = 'Closed Won'
            GROUP BY AccountId
        ]){
            wonOppAmounts.put((Id)ar.get('AccountId'), (Decimal)ar.get('sumAmount'));
        }

        for(AggregateResult ar : [
            SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) sumAmount
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdList AND StageName = 'Closed Lost'
            GROUP BY AccountId
        ]){
            lostOppAmounts.put((Id)ar.get('AccountId'), (Decimal)ar.get('sumAmount'));
        }

        // Update accounts with aggregated opportunity amounts
        for(Account acct : accountMap.values()){
            acct.Open_Opps_Amount__c = openOppAmounts.containsKey(acct.Id) ? openOppAmounts.get(acct.Id) : 0;
            acct.Closed_Won_Opps_Amount__c = wonOppAmounts.containsKey(acct.Id) ? wonOppAmounts.get(acct.Id) : 0;
            acct.Closed_Lost_Opps_Amount__c = lostOppAmounts.containsKey(acct.Id) ? lostOppAmounts.get(acct.Id) : 0;
            System.debug('Account ' + acct.Name + ' updated with Open: ' + acct.Open_Opps_Amount__c + ', Won: ' + acct.Closed_Won_Opps_Amount__c + ', Lost: ' + acct.Closed_Lost_Opps_Amount__c);
        }
        update accountMap.values();

        // Prepare emails
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for (Id accountId : accountToContactsMap.keySet()) {
            Account relatedAccount = accountMap.get(accountId);
            Decimal openAmount = openOppAmounts.containsKey(relatedAccount.Id) ? openOppAmounts.get(relatedAccount.Id) : 0;
            Decimal closedWonAmount = wonOppAmounts.containsKey(relatedAccount.Id) ? wonOppAmounts.get(relatedAccount.Id) : 0;
            Decimal closedLostAmount = lostOppAmounts.containsKey(relatedAccount.Id) ? lostOppAmounts.get(relatedAccount.Id) : 0;

            for (Contact c : accountToContactsMap.get(accountId)) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'hreniuc91@gmail.com'});
                mail.setReplyTo('hello@world.com');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Scheduled Apex Batch');
                mail.setSubject(relatedAccount.Name + ' : Opportunities Amount, based on Stage!');
                mail.setHtmlBody(
                    '<p>Below is a table of opportunities related to the account: ' + relatedAccount.Name + '.</p>' +
                    '<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Account</strong></td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Stage</strong></td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Amount</strong></td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + relatedAccount.Name + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Open</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + openAmount + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + relatedAccount.Name + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Closed Won</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + closedWonAmount + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + relatedAccount.Name + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Closed Lost</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">' + closedLostAmount + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>'
                );
                mails.add(mail);
                System.debug('Prepared email for contact: ' + c.Email);
            }
        }

        // Send all emails
        try {
            if (!mails.isEmpty()) {
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
                System.debug('Emails sent successfully: ' + mails.size());
            } else {
                System.debug('No emails to send');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error sending emails: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.debug('No accounts to process');
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    System.debug('Finish method initiated');
  }
}


global class ScheduleOppAmountForAccount implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        OppAmountForAccount batchJob = new OppAmountForAccount();

    Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
  }
}


So what exactly is your error? Where does it stop? Your execute method has a ton of things going on, maybe breaking that up into smaller methods you'll be able to test and debug each step along the way.

I'm not receiving the e-mails, i tried to debug but i still don't now why it does not send me the e-mails.

Do you have a test class where're your mocking the data and trying to send? If you're just using records in the UI do you have emails enabled in the sandbox? I am assuming you get a value in the mails.size() so the email is there trying to run.
You could also add in debug to see if the email was fired but I can't find that syntax right this moment.

Do you see the debug of the System.debug('Prepared email for contact: ' + c.Email); line?
